# Convert the date time in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpql

Hi I am new to java and JPQL. here I am passing the dateTime as parameter in my url of GET method. what I want is I want user should pass  date time in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format.But right now when I pass the  date time it is comapring with the current dateTime .I want it should compare the  reservations by the date and time passed by user.
 here is my  method and query. please help me..

```
@GET
    @Path("/getReservationByUserIdAndTypeAndDateTime/{userid}/{type}/{dateTime}")
    public List<Reservation> getReservationByAndUserIdAndTypeAndDateTime(@PathParam("userid") int uid, @PathParam("type") int tid,@PathParam("dateTime")String dateTime) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

        //Timestamp dateTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
     dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        //System.out.println("dateTime-"+dateTime);

        CriteriaQuery<Reservation> criteria = builder.createQuery(Reservation.class);
        Root<Reservation> r = criteria.from(Reservation.class);
        TypedQuery<Reservation> query = em.createQuery(
            criteria.select(r).where(new Predicate[]{
                    builder.equal(r.get(Reservation_.usersId), uid), 
                    builder.equal(r.get(Reservation_.reservationsType), tid),
                    builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                           builder.concat(r.get(Reservation_.date), r.get(Reservation_.time)), dateTime.toString())}));
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: The second line of your method resets the passed dateTime to the current dateTime. Why are you doing that? And you shouldn't use strings to manipulate date and time. Use Date or Calendar.

Answer (score 3):

It is Very Simple just use this method

`String myDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";`

```
public String formatDate(Date date)
{
    SimpleDateFormat customFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(myDateFormat );
    customFormat.setLenient(false);
    return customFormat.format(date);
}
```

you Can convert your Date in String into Date Object by `new Date('your date in String')`

Answer (score -1):

Try

`dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Integer.parseInt(dateTime));`

instead of

`dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());`

Your datetime which the user is passing should be in unix time stamp.

Comment: @Down marker: If you mark it down, could you at least explain why, please?

Comment: Because the answer doesn't answer the question. Because a unix timestamp is a long and not an Integer. Because the input doesn't get passed as a unix timestamp, and there's no reason to pass it as a unix timestamp. Because Integer doesn't have a parseString() method. Because DateFormat can't format an Integer. Do you want more?

Comment: Please, could you tell me How to convert my String date in '"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' .